# textblob .detect_language() function not working

Tags: python, textblob, language-detection

So I have been trying out coding and am currently finding some language detection packages and found out about textblob, but I am having some sort of proble.
This is my code:

```
# - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-
from textblob import TextBlob

blob = TextBlob("Comment vas-tu?")

print(blob.detect_language())

print(blob.translate(to='es'))
print(blob.translate(to='en'))
print(blob.translate(to='zh'))
```

and this error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(blob.detect_language())
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 568, in detect_language
    return self.translator.detect(self.raw)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\textblob\translate.py", line 72, in detect
    response = self._request(url, host=host, type_=type_, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\textblob\translate.py", line 92, in _request
    resp = request.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am still a little bit of a beginner in programming... Can I ask what I can do to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it working by doing some changes in your translate.py file as mentioned below:
Original:

```
url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=webapp&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=1"
```

Change above code to:

```
url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=te&format=html&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=1"
```

For further details visit this link: ["HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found" while using translation function in TextBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69338699/httperror-http-error-404-not-found-while-using-translation-function-in-textb/69367776#69367776)

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to do language detection, I see that **langdetect** library is a good fit:
https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/

Here is a demo on how to use it:

```
>>> from langdetect import detect
>>> detect('هيا بنا نلعب')
'ar'
>>>
```